# How to allow browser based pop up using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, popup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JXVJ.png)

I want to Allow camara and mic on click of Allow button on the popup. How can I handle this using selenium webdriver with python? Refer image below. 
I have tried following solution but it is not working for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='path-of- 
driver\chromedriver.exe')
```

Chrome version is : 78
selenium : 3.14
Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `media_stream_mic` and `media_stream_camera` in the experimental options

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1
})
```

Comment: I tried doing the same but it id not working